# Silverlight: TextTrimming

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, textblock

Is there a way to identify if `TextTrimming` is triggered?

For example in my first row, text is not trimmed because its only 20 characters, in my second row text are 1500 characters and it trims the text, is there a way to identify it, like `IsTextTrimmed` property?

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding test}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

Thank you

Comment: WordEllipsis does not work when Wrap is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation on the [TextWrapping property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(VS.95).aspx),

> You can detect clipped text
>   programmatically because ActualWidth
>   for a TextBlock always reports the
>   expanded size of the text, even if it
>   does not fit in the layout container.
>   If you know where to read the Width
>   for the layout container that is doing
>   the clipping, you can compare these
>   two values.

[image]